# Set width in meta viewport tag to match width of canvas element?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, meta-tags, viewport, meta

I have a canvas element with a width of 512 pixels and I want to set the viewport of mobile devices to match it 1:1.

I was able to achieve this in the Android Stock Browser on Samsung Galaxy S3 using the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=512,height=device-height,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=yes">
```

However, in Chrome for Android it only displays half of the canvas and in the Stock Browser on Samsung Galaxy S2 it only shows two thirds of it.

Isn't there a way to force the viewport to always display exactly 512 pixels in width?

Answer (score 2):

Take off the scaling params:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=512,height=device-height,user-scalable=no">
```